# How to set system time in C++ by using cross-platform code?

Tags: c++, qt, date, time, cross-platform

I am developing application on Qt/QML. I need to change current system time. It's strange, but I haven't found any cross-platform way to do it by using either Qt or C++. Can you suggeste me some cross-platform way to set up current date and time?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely it is not possible via Qt. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173637/set-system-clock-with-qt-on-linux

Comment: Yes, it is, this is why I am looking for some universal way. For now it looks like it does not exist...

Comment: There is no cross-platform way for C++ or Qt to set system time. You need to look for a external library which can do this or use system api

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-platform methods included in Qt SDK for this purpose.
You have to code it by yourself, depending on your target OS list.